# How to run a bash script via absolute path?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell, bash-completion

I've already posted this question here:

https://superuser.com/questions/1067609/how-to-run-a-bash-script-via-absolute-path

But I hope that maybe If I duplicate it here, I will get my answer sooner :)

I have a file:

```
/Users/danylo.volokh/test/test_bash_script.sh
```

Content is very simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "-- print from script"
```

I'm in folder "danylo.volokh"

**This command runs fine:**

```
Danilos-MacBook-Pro:~ danylo.volokh$ test/test_bash_script.sh 
-- print from script
```

**But if I try to run in with absolute path I get an error:**

```
Danilos-MacBook-Pro:~ danylo.volokh$ /test/test_bash_script.sh 
-bash: /test/test_bash_script.sh: No such file or directory
```

I want to run a command with absolute path from any folder and get the script to be executed.

Comment: You should fix your understanding of absolute path, absolute path is `/Users/danylo.volokh/test/test_bash_script.sh` not `/test/test_bash_script.sh `

Comment: Please don't cross-post. I can assure you this will only irritate people, not "get your answer sooner"; SuperUser is entirely appropriate for your question. Also, your question at SU *already had two answers* when you posted here.

Comment: Thanks for a good advice. Actually I already got my answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 
It is a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/1067609/how-to-run-a-bash-script-via-absolute-path

Actually I already got -2 for duplicating this. Can I fix it somehow ?

Comment: You could simply delete this question. (Please be aware that *repeatedly* deleting your own question will affect your reputation negatively, though.)

Answer (score 2):

Your path in incorrect. You should run:

```
/Users/danylo.volokh/test/test_bash_script.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

`/test/test_bash_script.sh` looks for the file from the root directory! Your path should be from the root, not from the current directory.

Try `/Users/danylo.volokh/test/test_bash_script.sh`.